# Dollar ($) character used in resource.GetObject

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, string, icons

I just spotted this line in an old Windows Forms app (created by the designer):

`this.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon")));`

it seems to be using [ResourceManager.GetObject()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/963f81yd.aspx) in order to get the icon. My question is regarding the significance of the `$` prefixing `this`.  There is no mention of the dollar symbol in the docs.

Does the dollar have a special meaning (reflection possibly?) or merely just to do with the implementation of `GetObject()`?

In addition where is the icon actually stored?

Comment: And how is the corresponding resource (Icon) defined in the resx file?

Comment: @HenkHolterman - Ok I think you helped me answer my own question.  I'd forgotton about the .resx files (haven't touched WinForms for ages) and there is is, defined as `$this.Icon`.

Answer (score 3):

This is a pretty standard trick used in .NET, the compiler uses it too when it needs to generate a name for a auto-generated class or field.  Using a character like `$` ensures that there can never be a name collision with an identifier in the program.

There isn't much chance of that when you only program in C#, *this* is a keyword.  But certainly in other languages.  You could for example create a VB.NET Winforms project, drop a button on the form and name it "this".  When you localize the form, the button's Text property source appears as:

```
  <data name="this.Text" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Button1</value>
  </data>
```

That would be a name collision with the form's Text property resource if it didn't put the $ in front of it.  Not until you program in a language that permits $ in an identifier name anyway.  None of the standard VS languages do.

Yet another detail is that you'll have trouble referencing that button from C# code.  There's an escape hatch for that as well, you can use @this in your code.  The @ prefix makes sure that the compiler doesn't recognize it as a keyword but just a plain identifier.

Answer (score 1):

The WinForms designer actually dumps quite a bit of hidden items like this into the resource file (.resx) assocaited with each form in order to support, mostly, internationalization (though other designer meta-data is there as well).  While text and icons may be obvious, even layout information can be there.  I suppose those German words are pretty long so when internationalizaing the form you may actually need to change label widths.

The $ I would assume is a way to make sure the designer-added resources don't conflict with user resources.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the icon is stored within the corresponding `.resx` file and was actually defined with the dollar prefix `$this.Icon`.  This would imply that the dollar doesn't have a special meaning at all.

Comment: Is the special meaning rather that the assembly icon is accessible using '$this.Icon' and the assembly icon doesn't need to be added to a resx